# Can't connect a Bluetooth keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

Setting determines a keyboard, it't logitech K480. After pressing to connect, it says can't connect. Checked keyboard on other devices pairs ok. 
Same things happen to the bluetooth speakers.

Comment: There's some known bug in the bluetooth plug and developers are working on this.I think you'll find possible related issues here [https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-bluetooth/issues](https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-bluetooth/issues). Hopefully, will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem by myself. installed other bluetooth managing app from appcenter. Up and running.

Comment: Hi! I'm having the same problem with the same keyboard. Which bt manager did you install?